# drwxr -xr -x 2 what is the meaning of 2

Tags: linux, command-line, command

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 vivekray vivekray     4096 2012-01-02 14:09 Templates
```

what is the meaning of 2.

if you have some time please reply me thanx.

Comment: Ignoring my answer for a second, I thought hard links do not work for directories, but only files? Or is that only true for Linux systems and the OP isn't using Linux?

Comment: @dominikh: Every directory `foo` has at least 2 hard links: `foo` and `foo/.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the number of hard links referencing that file/blob of data. The 2 means that there are two different names (`Templates` being one of those) for the same file.

Note that this only works for hard links and not symbolic links (links created with `ln -s`). Also note that the other name of that file will also have a count of 2.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers have explained, the number is a count of hard links to the file. However, since your "file" is a directory, the meaning is a little different than usual.

Directories in Unix-like systems always have at least two links to them. One is the directory's entry in its parent directory and the other is the "." entry in its own listing. If there are any sub-directories within a directory, each one caused an additional link to its parent from its ".." entry.

So the extra bit of info you can get from that number is that Templates has no sub-directories.

Answer (score 2):

It's the number of hard links to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Number of links: Second field specifies the number of links for that file. In this example, 2 indicates that there are 2 links to this directory entry.

Comment: thanx rkosegi i got it .